# matplotlib plot Label along plot line

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

One for the matplotlib community:

Say I have a straight line give by:

```
plot([37, 45], [-0.67778, -0.67778], '--k', lw=1.2)
```

Am I able to add a label to this line along the line rather than in the legend? i.e., something similar to the following (but rather than a contour plot, just an ordinary line plot):

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is an example simply to show how it can be done without consideration for appearance. For more information about annotating plots please see this [detailed demonstration](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/annotation_demo.html).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [37, 45]; y = [-0.67778, -0.67778]

# as an example for where to place the text we can use the mean
xmean = sum(i for i in x) / float(len(x))
ymean = sum(i for i in y) / float(len(y))

plt.plot(x, y, '--k', lw=1.2)
plt.annotate('some text', xy=(xmean,ymean), xycoords='data')
plt.show() # or plt.savefig('filename.png')
```

Yields:

[image: _soannotate.png]