# Python 3 - matplitlib text inside vertical line

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to use `matplotlib` from Python 3 to achieve something like the image shown below:

[image]

Similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26768322/matplotlib-plot-label-along-plot-line) but accepted answer is not sufficient for my need. I need to add text in the middle of dotted line (which I can plot with `plt.axvline()` function).

Here is what I tried

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
plt.hist(some_data)
plt.axvline(0.5, color='k', linestyle='--')
plt.text(0.5, 0.5, 'Some Text', ha='center', va='center',rotation='vertical')
plt.show()
```

If I can put this text in the middle of dotted line, it will be great.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This isn't a solution but more of a workaround really. You could try setting the background colour for the text or adding a bounding box to it with a specific colour which will eclipse the line. This will make the text appear inline.

You would implement this like so:

```
plt.text(0.5, 0.5, 'Some Text', ha='center', va='center',rotation='vertical', backgroundcolor='white')
```

[image]

and

```
plt.text(0.5, 0.5, 'Some Text', ha='center', va='center',rotation='vertical', bbox={'facecolor':'white', 'pad':5})
```

[image]

Of course a problem arises when this line is being overlaid on a histogram of a different colour and you would then have to match the colour of background or box to the histogram. This would display something like so:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)